# Updating this.state.dataSource doesn't update ListView

Tags: react-native

I have a ListView like:

```
<ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderMovie}
      style={styles.listView}
/>
```

It displays rows like:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this,movie)}>

        <Image
          source={{uri: movie.uri}}
          style={styles.thumbnail}
        />
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{movie.id}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.year}>{movie.votes}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```

I have a function that updates this.state.dataSource with the number of "votes" a movie has.  But these changes aren't reflected in the UI, but when I log the this.state.dataSource, the changes are there.  Do I need to somehow re-render the rows?  Shouldn't they automatically change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make React-native re-render the rows, you need to create a copy of the array, update your object, and then use setState with your newly created array. For example:

```
let newArray = this.state.dataSource.slice();
newArray[indexToUpdate] = {
  ...this.state.dataSource[indexToUpdate],
  field: newValue,
};
this.setState({
  dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray),
});
```

Reference:

- [React-Native Updating List View DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738671/react-native-updating-list-view-datasource)
- [ListView does not re-render a row when property of an object in datasource array is changed #4104](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4104)

Answer (score 10):

I have a similar situation and the only thing I had to do is:

```
this.setState({
  dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(new_data_for_datasource)
})
```

It works fine for me.
In the class constructor I have the following code:

```
this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
})
this.state = {
  dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.original_data)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem that I see is that you have a "new_data_for_datasource", but my new datasource would be the current datasource.  As in, I change this.state.dataSource.   So I can't do  dataSource:this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.dataSource) right? As in, I don't have a new dataSource object.  I guess I could set one as a copy of the current state's datasource?

Comment: I don't understand how you reload the ListView without the datasource updating.
Could you show me the code where you create the initial dataSource? In this dataSource you had to use cloneWithRows passing some data or the dataSource came from a previous Component, passed by props?

Comment: `fetchData: function() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.gifs),
          loaded: true,
        });
      })
      .done();
  },`

Comment: ^that's how I fetch the data originally

Answer (score 0):

I am calling a function to fetch new data and updating the list view with clone option like below :

```
fetchCarData(datax) {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL + '&' + 'place=' + datax)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            this.setState({
                dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData),
                loaded: true,
            });
            if (responseData.notfound === 'yes') {
                alert('No Vehicles found');
                this.setState({
                    notfound: 'Not found vehicles, do another search'
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    notfound: ''
                })
            }
        })
        .done();
}
```