# React-Native Updating List View DataSource

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, datasource, react-native

I have an iOS app I am making with react-native. The Game class contains a ListView component. I set the state in the constructor and include a `dataSource`. I have a hardcoded array of data for right now that I store in a different state property (`this.state.ds`). Then in the `componentDidMount` I use the `cloneWithRows` method to clone my `this.state.ds` as my dataSource for the view. That is pretty standard as far as ListViews go and is working well. Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

 var React = require("react-native");
 var { StyleSheet, Text, View, ListView, TouchableHighlight } = React;

class Games extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2
    });
    this.state = {
        ds: [
            { AwayTeam: "TeamA", HomeTeam: "TeamB", Selection: "AwayTeam" },
            { AwayTeam: "TeamC", HomeTeam: "TeamD", Selection: "HomeTeam" }
        ],
        dataSource: ds
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.ds)
    });
}
pressRow(rowData) {
    var newDs = [];
    newDs = this.state.ds;
    newDs[0].Selection = newDs[0] == "AwayTeam" ? "HomeTeam" : "AwayTeam";
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newDs)
    });
}

renderRow(rowData) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => this.pressRow(rowData)}
            underlayColor="#ddd"
        >
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>
                    {rowData.AwayTeam} @ {rowData.HomeTeam}{" "}
                </Text>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Text style={styles.selectionText}>
                        {rowData[rowData.Selection]}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
render() {
    return (
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        />
    );
}
}
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
 row: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: 18,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#d7d7d7"
},
selectionText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    paddingTop: 3,
    color: "#b5b5b5",
    textAlign: "right"
}
});


module.exports = Games
```

The issue I am having comes in the `pressRow` method. When the user presses the row, I would like the selection to change and for it to render the change on the device. Through some debugging, I have noticed that even though I am changing the `Selection` property of the object in the `newDs` array, the same property changes on the object in `this.state.ds` and similarly changes the object in `this.state.dataSource._dataBlob.s1`. Through further debugging, I have found that since those other arrays have changed, the ListView's DataSource object doesn't recognize the change because when I set the state and `rowHasChanged` is called, the array it is cloning matches the array `this.state.dataSource._dataBlob.s1` and so it doesn't look like a change and doesn't rerender.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
pressRow(rowData){

    var newDs = [];
    newDs = this.state.ds.slice();
    newDs[0].Selection = newDs[0] == "AwayTeam" ? "HomeTeam" : "AwayTeam";
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newDs)
    })

}
```

This should make a copy of the array, which can then be modified independently of the original array in `this.state.ds`.

Comment: Thanks so much! There was one other step I had to do to make it work. For some reason I had to 'clear' the object I was trying to change. So I just made `newDs[0]` equal to a new object and gave it the properties of the object i was trying to change. Of course I changed the `Selection` property though.

Comment: Change `this.state.ds.slice()` to `this.state.ds.slice(0)` for better performance.

Comment: @TheNickyYo - why is that? The docs said undefined is treated as 0 anyway?

Comment: `this.state.ds.slice()` is not a function

Answer (score 18):

In case anyone comes across this issue like I did, here's the complete solution.

Basically, there seems to be a bug with the ListView component and you need to rebuild each item that changes in the datasource for the ListView to redraw it.

First, create the datasource and a copy of the array and save them to state.  In my case, `foods` is the array.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
    });
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(foods),
        db: foods,
    };
}
```

When you want to change something in the datasource, make a copy of the array you saved to the state, rebuild the item with the change and then save the new array with the change back to the state (both db and datasource).

```
onCollapse(rowID: number) {
    console.log("rowID", rowID);
    var newArray = this.state.db.slice();
    newArray[rowID] = {
        key: newArray[rowID].key,
        details: newArray[rowID].details,
        isCollapsed: newArray[rowID].isCollapsed == false ? true : false,
    };
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray),
        db: newArray,
    });
}
```

Comment: Instead of manually rebuilding the whole object, you should be able to do: `var copy = Object.assign({}, obj);` per MDN documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Or if you prefer ES6 syntax: `newRows[rowId] = {
      ...this._sampleData[rowId],
      favorited: rowData.favorited ? false : true
    }`

Comment: May this.db instead of this.state.db be better?

Answer (score 3):

react is smart enough to detect changes in dataSource and if the list should be re-rendered. If you want to update listView, create new objects instead of updating the properties of existing objects.
The code would look something like this:

```
let newArray = this._rows.slice();
newArray[rowID] = {
  ...this._rows[rowID],
  Selection: !this._rows[rowID].Selection,
};
this._rows = newArray;

let newDataSource = this.ds.cloneWithRows(newArray);
this.setState({
  dataSource: newDataSource
});
```

You can read more about similar [issue on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4104)