# React Native Listview fetch from db-models?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

I'm working with react-native-db-models node module. I have 3 rows on my database model. =>  ( title | privateid | action )

I lose 2 days for this workout. I want to list all records from database. What's wrong?

```
var Download = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
      return {
        dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
          rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
        })
      };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
      this.fetchData();
    },

    fetchData: function () {
      DB.downloads.get_all(function(result) {
         var data = [];
         for(var i = 1; i <= result.totalrows; i++) {
           console.log(result.rows[i]);
           data[i-1] = result.rows[i];
           this.setState({
             dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(result.rows[i]),
             loaded:false,
           })
         }

       });

    },
    render: function () {
      return (
        <ListView
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderRow={this.renderTrack}
         style={styles.listView}/>
      );
    },
    renderTrack: function (track) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{track.title}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  });
```

Comment: Maybe you could give us more of an idea where it's gone south. Are you getting anything back from `DB.downloads.get_all(function(result)`? What happens if you console.log(result)?

I think this...
dataSource.cloneWithRows(result.rows[i])

should be this...
`dataSource.cloneWithRows(data)`

and how you're building the data array looks odd to me too. At the very least shouldn't it be `data.push(results.row[i])`? This assumes that `console.log(result.rows[i]);` returns an object.

Hope that helps, but more info would really help me help you

Comment: @Chris, console.log(result) is working good. console.log(data) and console.log(result.rows[i]) working good in "for" function but i setState is not working in "for" function. when i do outside "for", its returning "undefineded" :|

Comment: There seems to be a lot of this going around right now. See if this helps you out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426760/react-native-listview-not-updating-on-data-change/33428564?noredirect=1#comment54667379_33428564

Answer (score 0):

Do this...

```
  fetchData: function () {
  DB.downloads.get_all(function(result) {
     var data = [];
     for(var i = 1; i <= result.totalrows; i++) {
       data.push(result.rows[i]);
     }
     // Outside of the loop, apply the data
       this.setState({
         dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(data),
         loaded:false,
       })
   });

},
```