# How force redraw ListView when this.state changed (but not the dataSource).

Tags: listview, react-native

I created a component that use a `ListView` to display a list of contacts. When clicking on a row, I update an array in the `state`'s component that contains all the selected contacts. However, I'm not using this array as a `dataSource` for my `ListView` component.

I would like to redraw the `ListView` each time this array is modified in order to display an image for the selected contacts.

Here is an example of my current situation:

```
renderListView: function(){
    <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
        style={styles.listView}
    />
}
renderRow:function(row){
    return if(this.state.something === true) <Text>Something</Text>
   else <Text>Something Else</Text>
}
```

I tried to call `.forceUpdate()`, it calls the `render` method but not the `renderRow` method.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you set something up on rnplay.org that we can play with?

Comment: I just came across this. claims to be an updatable listview component for both iOS and Android with pull-to-refresh. Looks sweet. Thought it might be helpful.
https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-listview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had this same issue.  Check out my question here:  [React Native ListView not updating on data change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426760/react-native-listview-not-updating-on-data-change/)

Basically, there seems to be a bug with the ListView component and you need to rebuild each item that changes in the datasource for the ListView to redraw it.

Here's a working example:
https://rnplay.org/apps/GWoFWg

First, create the datasource and a copy of the array and save them to state.  In my case, `foods` is the array.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
    });
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(foods),
        db: foods,
    };
}
```

When you want to change something in the datasource, make a copy of the array you saved to the state, rebuild the item with the change and then save the new array with the change back to the state (both db and datasource).

```
onCollapse(rowID: number) {
    console.log("rowID", rowID);
    var newArray = this.state.db.slice();
    newArray[rowID] = {
        key: newArray[rowID].key,
        details: newArray[rowID].details,
        isCollapsed: newArray[rowID].isCollapsed == false ? true : false,
    };
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray),
        db: newArray,
    });
}
```

Comment: I just came across this. claims to be an updatable listview component for both iOS and Android with pull-to-refresh. Looks sweet. Thought it might be helpful.
https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-listview