# React-native update datasource

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I found similar questions but nothing works. If I click a list item I get error "undefined is not a function this.state.datasource.slice()"

I try to make all "ordered" true

Comment: could you show all file content?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really want to slice your array -> Try:

```
this.state.dataSource.slice(1,2)
```

according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) you have to define a beginning and an end to slice like so:

```
arr.slice([begin[, end]])
```

Comment: If I remove slice I get "rowHasChange true "/n" defaultGetRowData true "/n" true "/n" defaultGetSectionHeaderData true "/n" and some more trues. (i put /n to show that its change line) check this link the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738671/react-native-updating-list-view-datasource

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? hard to help you with just error messages and no guidance

Comment: I try to change some values on datasource i this case to make all "ordered" ="true"

Answer (score 0):

If you looked at the `ListView` [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html), when you initialize the `dataSource` for your `ListView` component, you can supply a method that tells the `ListView` if the `dataSource` has changed, so that the `ListView` will re-render.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (e1, e2) => e1 !== e2});
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([/* initial data */]),
  };
}
```